# mutate string with condition

Tags: r, dplyr, stringr, stringi

Given the following example

```
status <- c("Open", "In Progress", "DevTest", "Stage Test: mw", "Stage Test: customer", "DevDone", "Done")

a <- c("Open, Open")
b <- c("Open, In Progress, DevTest, DevTest")
c <- c("DevTest, Done")
d <- c("Done, Done")

data <- tibble(status = c(a, b, c, d))
```

Now I want mutate an additional column with the following condition

- If status **only** contains "Open" -> Open
- If status contains "In Progress" **or** "DevTest" -> "In Progress"
- If status contains **only** "Done" -> "Done"

So the result should look like

| status | status_simple |
| --- | --- |
| Open, Open | Open |
| Open, In Progress, DevTest, DevTest | In Progress |
| DevTest, Done | In Progress |
| Done, Done | Done |

Comment: Is the first line of your code at all important for this example?

Answer (score 0):

This is a case where `case_when` can be very useful, to sort through the conditions and their consequence, in combination with `grepl`, to search for patterns in the character strings (and returns boolean vectors, which is what `case_when` expects):

```
data %>% mutate(
  status_simple = case_when(
    grepl("DevTest|In Progress", status) ~ "In Progress",
    grepl("Open", status) ~ "Open",
    grepl("Done", status) ~ "Done",
    ))
```

And the result:

```
# A tibble: 4 × 2
  status                              status_simple
  <chr>                               <chr>       
1 Open, Open                          Open        
2 Open, In Progress, DevTest, DevTest In Progress 
3 DevTest, Done                       In Progress 
4 Done, Done                          Done
```

Comment: Many thanks for the answer. This is working in this case but with more status and in a different order this is not working reliable. Can tell exactly what is the issue but the result is not correct.

Comment: Would you like to update your question with an example that does not give the correct result?